# Save under current file name with date attached

Tags: excel, vba

I have several Excel files to save under their current file name with today's date attached but in a different folder.

As these files all have different names my approach is get their file name as a variable and use it for the name to save under. Since I want to avoid writing a macro for each file, the idea of putting the desired name into one cell and then using that value (which works) for saving it, is not an option.

```vb
Sub Save_Workbook()

' Save Sheet with Current Date
' Adjust Absolute Path to Location Where to Save the Workbook

Dim FName As String

FName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\ME\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\SHEETS1\SHEETS2\ FName " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY" & ".xlsx"))

End Sub
```

This macro saves the file in the desired folder and with the date attached, but it does not pick up the self-defined variable **FName**. The resulting file name is *FName 29-09-2018* for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included `FName` within the string so it's being treated as just text.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\ME\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\SHEETS1\SHEETS2\ FName " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY" & ".xlsx"))
```

should be

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\ME\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\SHEETS1\SHEETS2\" & FName & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY" & ".xlsx"))
```

or you could remove `FName` completely and use the `ActiveWorkbook.Name`:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\ME\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\SHEETS1\SHEETS2\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY" & ".xlsx"))
```

You may want to add a space between `FName` and the date.  Rather than include an extra `& " " &` next to `Fname` you could use:

```
Format(Now(), " DD-MM-YYYY" & ".xlsx")
```

This adds the extra space in the date formatting.

Comment: Thanks, @Darren your solution works. There is one minor though. `ActiveWorkbook.Name` includes the original file extension, so currently the result is **Sheetname.xlsm 30-08-2018.xlsx** No exactly what is needed. Is there a way to remove the _.xlsm_ from the original file name?